# swift adding zoom to container view

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift, github

I have a page view controller embedded inside a container view in order to swipe between images. But now I am trying to add a touch that will make the image go full screen "lightbox" with zoom available and also swipe through the images while in full screen mode.

I can get it to work, and messing around with auto layout seems to be much work consider I have a lot of other stuff in that VC.

So does anyone know a good image slider from github written in swift? - without the need of cocopods.

thanks!

Answer (score -1):

It's easy enough to write one yourself. In full-screen mode, use another `UIPageViewController`, because it already has the swipe left & right support built in.